# Where do I define Views in a Fragment?

Tags: android, android-fragments, wear-os

I am working on a Wear app and have a `GridViewPager` to show several `Fragment`s. In my `Activity`, I want to be able to update the content of the `Fragment`:

```
public class LocationFragment extends Fragment {
    TextView tvHead;

    public void setLocation(String l) {
        tvLocation.setText(location);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {


        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_location, container, false);
        tvLocation = (TextView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.tvLocation);

        return rootView;
    }

}
```

The fragment is created and added to the grid view in my Activity's `onCreate()`:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_pages);

    pager = (GridViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
    MyGridPagerAdapter gridPagerAdapter = new MyGridPagerAdapter(this, getFragmentManager());

    frLocation = new LocationFragment();
    gridPagerAdapter.add(0, frLocation);
    pager.setAdapter(gridPagerAdapter);
}
```

In `onResume`, I call some network action that will result in a call to `frLocation.setLocation()`, however this call can come *before* `onCreateView`, causing the application to crash with a `NullPointerException` (because `tvLocation` is not set yet).

How should I set this up?

Comment: Wait sorry I see you're doing this in a fragment.  I'm guessing you have some network class triggering this method if so make sure the fragment has been inflated before triggering the method

Answer (score 1):

Usually, activities should not hold references to fragments (I assume that is what you are doing with frLocation) and vise versa because lifecycle events create them to be recreated and then the references are no longer valid (and might even cause memory leaks).

As for your specific issue, I suggest that the activity will hold the result of the network call and expose an interface to the fragment.

When the fragment's onCreateView() is called it will check the value on the activity and update the text if the value is valid. As for the other direction (data is updated after fragment view creation) it is a little trickier. The fragment can register itself to listen to changes when the view is created and de-register when view is destroyed (this way the when the network call is finished you can be sure that the TextView is valid).